# Exchange retention work cycle properties

Tags: exchange-2010, archive, email

I've setup retention tags and policies in Exchange, but only run when I execute `start-managedfolderassistant`

Upon running the command `get-mailboxserver | fl name,*workcycle*, *ManagedFolderAssistantSchedule*`, I noticed the following fields (truncated):

`ManagedFolderWorkCycle            : 1.00:00:00`

`ManagedFolderWorkCycleCheckpoint  : 1.00:00:00`

`ManagedFolderAssistantSchedule    : {Sun.1:00 AM-Sun.9:00 AM, Mon.1:00 AM-Mon.9:00 AM, Tue.1:00 AM-Tue.9:00 AM, Wed.1:00 AM-Wed.9:00 AM, Thu.1:00 AM-Thu.9:00 AM, Fri.1:00 AM-Fri.9:00 AM, Sat.1:00 AM-Sat.9:00 AM}`

The first two are set to run every day, but does this conflict with what is set in ManagedFolderAssistantSchedule?  What's the difference between ManagedFolderWorkCycle and ManagedFolderWorkCycleCheckpoint?

Comment: Is the ManagedFolderAssistantSchedule in the server's time or UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998651.aspx

and open the "parameters" pop-out to see what each parameter does.  That explains it better than I was getting ready to attempt.

Specifically:

The ManagedFolderWorkCycle parameter specifies the time span in which all mailboxes on the specified server will be processed by the Managed Folder Assistant. The Managed Folder Assistant applies retention policies according to the ManagedFolderWorkCycleCheckpoint interval.

The ManagedFolderWorkCycleCheckpoint parameter specifies the time span at which to refresh the list of mailboxes so that new mailboxes that have been created or moved will be part of the work queue. Also, as mailboxes are prioritized, existing mailboxes that haven't been successfully processed for a long time will be placed higher in the queue and will have a greater chance of being processed again in the same work cycle.

Comment: That helps.  But will the Managed Folder Assistant process run if ManagedFolderAssistantSchedule is null and run according to ManagedFolderWorkCycle ?